# Python ctypes in_dll string assignment

Tags: python, ctypes

I could use some help assigning to a global C variable in DLL using ctypes.

The following is an example of what I'm trying:

test.c contains the following

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    char name[60];

    void test(void) {
      printf("Name is %s\n", name);
    }
```

On windows (cygwin) I build a DLL (Test.dll) as follows:

```
gcc -g -c -Wall test.c
gcc -Wall -mrtd -mno-cygwin -shared -W1,--add-stdcall-alias -o Test.dll test.o
```

When trying to modify the `name` variable and then calling the C test function using the ctypes interface I get the following...

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> dll = windll.Test
>>> dll
<WinDLL 'Test', handle ... at ...>
>>> f = c_char_p.in_dll(dll, 'name')
>>> f
c_char_p(None)
>>> f.value = 'foo'
>>> f
c_char_p('foo')
>>> dll.test()
Name is Name is 4∞┘☺
13
```

Why does the test function print garbage in this case?

**Update:**

I have confirmed Alex's response.  Here is a working example:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> dll = windll.Test
>>> dll
<WinDLL 'Test', handle ... at ...>
>>> f = c_char_p.in_dll(dll, 'name')
>>> f
c_char_p(None)
>>> libc = cdll.msvcrt
>>> libc
<CDLL 'msvcrt', handle ... at ...>
#note that pointer is required in the following strcpy
>>> libc.strcpy(pointer(f), c_char_p("foo"))
>>> dll.test()
Name is foo
```

Comment: I voted up, but after doing some more checking, I think that there might be something else going on. I believe that the OP's original method of assigning a new string to `ctype.c_char_p.value` _is_ the correct approach. It works for me. I also think that that the `strcpy` approach might work here where name is malloc'd with 59+NUL characters, but in another situation could result in a segmentation fault.

Comment: one line of code worths thausand words: `f = c_char_p();buff="guarda mamma, senza mani!";f.value=buff;cast(f,POINTER(c_char))[0]="G";print(buff)`. To say `f.value= "something"` bounds f to something that will live a short life.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`name` is not really a character *pointer* (it's an array, which "decays to" a pointer when accessed, but can never be **assigned** to).  You'll need to call the `strcpy` function from the C runtime library, instead of assigning to `f.value`.

Comment: My only fear of this approach would be that `strcpy(copy, s)` is usually prefaced with a `copy = malloc(1 + strlen(s));` in order to make sure that you have space for your string. If you fail to do this, I believe that you might overwrite some other memory, if your "name" is longer that the 59 character buffer + terminating NULL that you allocated. Could end with a seg fault. [See the docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Copying-and-Concatenation.html). Something like `strdup` that allocates memory on the fly is usually used, but I don't think you could do that in Python.