# OS X: python ctypes global variables

Tags: python, c, macos, ctypes, setuptools

I am trying to create Python ctypes bindings to a project written using the C99 standard. The current C code uses a few global variables (e.g. `b`, `c`, and `d`) in conjunction with a top level function (e.g. `mod_run`).

**Example: `model.c`**

```
#include <mod_def.h>
#include <mod_run.h>

struct_b *b;
int       d

int
mod_run(int                  rec,
        double               state,
        struct_a            *a)
{
    extern struct_c     c;

// code that uses a, b, c, d, rec, state
// and functions defined in mod_def.h and mod_run.h

}
```

I have successfully created a shared object (e.g. `model.so`) using the`setuptools.extension` module but have not been able to load the object using `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary`.

```python
In [1]: from ctypes import *

In [2]: cdll.LoadLibrary('model.so')

OSError: dlopen(model.so, 6): Symbol not found: _X
  Referenced from: model.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

where `X` is a global variable declared in `mod_def.h`:

```c
extern size_t X;
```

Finally, my question.  Do I need to create a wrapper around `mod_run` that will allow me to export each of the global variables defined in my example code?  Or is it possible, somehow, to load the shared object as it, without having defined `X`?

I have looked at these related topics but have not found anything that solves my problem:

- [Mapping a global variable from a shared library with ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544173/mapping-a-global-variable-from-a-shared-library-with-ctypes)
- [Python ctypes in_dll string assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867916/python-ctypes-in-dll-string-assignment)

**Update (05/20/2015):**

How I'm building the shared object:

```python
setup(name='model',
      ...
      ext_modules=[Extension(
          'model',
          sources=sources,  # list of c sources using absolute paths
          include_dirs=includes,  # list of include directories using absolute paths
          extra_compile_args=['-std=c99'],
          # extra_link_args=['-lmodule_with_globals']  # does not build with this option: ld: library not found for -lmodule_with_globals
          )])
```

Using OSX 10.10.3 and Python 3.4.3 :: Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64).

Comment: I suspect you need to use a relative path (such as `./model.so`) in your `LoadLibrary` call, otherwise it would only search system directories for the file.

Comment: @Frxstrem - I'm using absolute paths in the build.  I also don't think it is a path issue since `X` should be in `model.so`.

Comment: @eryksun - Thanks for the idea.  Do you have an example of how to use `-lmodule_with_globals` with `setuptools`.  Adding it as shown above (Update 05/20/2015) doesn't work. Same goes for your second idea.

Comment: @eryksun - duh.  Now I get it.  The code I'm working with is a stand-alone c module so there shouldn't need to be any linking with other modules.

Comment: Oh, don't declare the variables as `extern` if they're defined in the same module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the variable `X` is defined in a header file but is never allocated anywhere in the code.
    extern size_t X;

to fix this, I created a wrapper file called `globals.c` and in it simply put:

```
// globals.c
#include <mod_def.h>
#include <mod_run.h>

size_t X;
// allocation of other global variables
```

and just like that,

```
from ctypes import *
# load the library (this was failing before)
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('model.so')

# create a python variable that maps to the global X
X = c_sizet.in_dll(lib, 'X')
# assign a value to the global X
X.value = 2
```

The allocation could have been in a header of one of the existing source files but in my case, that's now how we wanted to have the module work.